# Why can a class instance be converted to an interface without implementation relationship, but not to a class without inheritance relationship?

Tags: java, casting

I have a Person class and an empty class called MyClass and an empty interface called MyInterface. There is no relationship between the Person, MyClass and MyInterface.

When I cast a Person instance to MyInterface, the compilation passes, but when I cast a Person instance to MyClass, the compilation fails. Why is that?

Below is my code:

```
class Person {
    public String name;
}

class MyClass {}

interface MyInterface {}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Compile passed
        MyInterface myInterface = (MyInterface) new Person();

        // Compile error
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) new Person();
    }
}
```

Comment: Casting to arbitrary interfaces is allowed because the compiler only sees `new Person()` as an expression with type `Person` - it doesn't know if it is `Person` directly, or a subtype of `Person` which also implements `MyInterface`. By contrast, because `MyClass` is a class, it knows that it isn't a subclass or superclass of `Person`, so knows the cast would fail at runtime.

Comment: Yes, because a *subclass* of `Person` could implement `MyInterface`.

Comment: I know now, thanks @Andy Turner.

Comment: I look back on this issue, I am confused again. I think the compiler should throw an error. If ```Person``` does not implement ```MyInterface```, then code "```MyInterface myInterface = (MyInterface) new Person()```" will eventually report an error, whether happens compile-time or runtime, because it's impossible that the actual object at runtime is a subclass of ```Person``` and implemented ```MyInterface```. In other words, it makes no sense to allow this line of code to pass the compilation check. The compiler can identify such errors at compile time without actually executing it.